# Showing ERROR message "Unable to create ext4 partition"

Tags: system-installation, partitioning

I have a Lenovo IdeaPad u510 laptop with 1TB HDD and 24GB SSD. It had a Genuine Windows 8 previously installed. But I wanted to install **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit** in it. So that I have wiped all the partitions (also recovery partitions) to install only **Ubuntu**, but at the installation state after creating the partition table and choosing the username the installation process is being stopped showing "The ext4 file system creation in partition #2 of SCSI2 (0,0,0) (sdb) failed." I have tried with UEFI boot ON, Legacy boot ON, secured boot OFF but it's always showing the same error message. This laptop currently has no OS. Is the machine bricked or how can I solve this problem?

Comment: take a screenshot of your gparted partition editor.Then upload it to imgur.com and post back the link here.In ubuntu 14.04, the gparted utility is not preinstalled. So run these commands on terminal to install gparted.(`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gparted`)

Comment: I have solved this problem! I have created a EFI partition through GParted. After staring 'Try Ubuntu' I used GParted to create a 200 MiB FAT32 partition labeled 'EFI' and then tried installing. It's not showing the ERROR message now. :)

Comment: post the above comment as answer. So that it would be useful for someone like you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem! I have created a EFI partition through **GParted**. After starting 'Try Ubuntu' I used GParted to create a 200 MiB FAT32 partition labeled 'EFI' and then tried installing. It's not showing the ERROR message now. :)